# How can I use multiple pre-trained model without TF-slim?

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model, transfer-learning

I want to use/combine different parts of different pre-trained models into one model. For example, I want to use the first few layers (with the pre-trained weights) of ResNet as encoder and then combine them with a decoder from another model, and then I want to train further on that. Is there a way, preferably without using TF-slim? I'm using TensorFlow 1.4.